# Magento 1.9: How to configure Bubble Elasticsearch to search products only by title?

Tags: magento-1.9, elasticsearch

Now on my search results by "red" keyword appear results with title without "red", so it search in product description I think.

How to avoid this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open description and short description attribute from admin side and set NO to "Use in quick search". Hope it will work.

Comment: It works, but some products still appear in search results. Because those category has substring "red". Can you help with this?

Comment: Set No to all product attribute and it may help.